# How can i access the files in the nand flash memory through linux terminal?

Tags: linux, files, terminal, memory, sd-card

I have files in the nand flash memory of my Gumstix Overo that i want to copy to a SD card, but i can't access them through the overo terminal, so i wanted to copy them through the linux terminal but i don't know how. Can someone help me?

I have done the `mount` command and it gives me this:

```
debian@OCR-1:~$ mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
mdev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)
none on /debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
ubi0:rootfs on /mnt/rootfs type ubifs (ro,noatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /var/log type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=continue,commit=1,barrier=1,data=ordered)
/dev/mmcblk0p4 on /var/archive type ext3 (ro,noatime,errors=continue,barrier=1,data=ordered)
debian@OCR-1:~$
```

but i don't know if this helps me access nand.

After i put an empty sd card, it doesn't appear on the mount command:

```
debian@OCR-1:~$ mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
mdev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)
none on /debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
ubi0:rootfs on /mnt/rootfs type ubifs (ro,noatime)
debian@OCR-1:~$
```

Comment: Run `mount` to see what filesystems are mounted. Check manuals and if that doesn't help, contact support

Comment: @Panki I updated the question with the mount command

Comment: Well, did you check if your files are somewhere there? `/mnt/rootfs` for example?

Comment: @Panki I found the files that i was looking for, thank you. Just another doubt, the sd card on the code above is /dev/mmcblk0p1? And to copy files to that sd card, do i use cp or dd?

Comment: You should not use `dd`, unless you are trying to write to it as a block device. To simply copy files, use `cp`. `/dev/mmcblk0p1` is the block device, and it's mounted on `/var/log/`.

Comment: @Panki I am sorry to bother you one last time, but when i put and empty sd card inside, it doesn't appear on the mount command, i updated the image on the question.

Comment: Please undo that edit and include the new output *below* it. You are now missing those devices and mounts - try running `mount -a`, if that doesn't help, get technical support I guess